# How to configure nested multi module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up a nested multi module project with gradle.
I have the following structure:

```
stock-client-root
|-- settings.gradle
|-- build.gradle
|-- stock-client
|   |-- build.gradle
|-- stock-ui
    |-- build.gradle
```

The problem is, that I cannot import any dependencies that are declared in the build.gradle files except spring boot related things.

Example: I want to use javafx. I declared it in the stock-ui/build.gradle file but when I want to import it in the module, intelliJ tells me, it cannot resolve that dependency.

I tried almost everything to solve this:

- Reload the project via gradle
- Restart the IDE
- Invalidate cache + rebuild project
- Created a new project with that structure and tried it again

**Can anyone point out, where the problem might be?**

And here is the content of the files:

**stock-client-root/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'stock-client-root'
include 'stock-client'
include 'stock-ui'
```

**stock-client-root/build.gradle**

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = 'com.demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**stock-client/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**stock-ui/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '13.0.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share project sample for investigation?

Comment: The project can be found [here](https://github.com/EyedPeas/gradle_problem)

Comment: Please check related documentation part: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: It seems like the problem is not an openjfx problem. It doesn't matter which depenedy I try to import.

Comment: Please check if dependency has classes under "External Libraies" node in project tree.

Comment: The dependency does not have classes in "External Libraries". 
But i found something strange.. 
I cloned a working multi module project and tried to import the openjfx dependencies the way shown in my question.. and it works... But i can't find any differences between the setups or the settings or anything...:/

Comment: You said that you'd already tried to crate new project and it hadn't helped. Probably different Gradle version is use in working project?

Comment: Yes, I tried to create a new project.
The working project is older... And I don't understand why it worked in the older project but not in the new one..

Comment: Have you compared Gradle versions?

Comment: Are you trying to import class from external dependency in the same module where this dependency is declared in build.gradle? If you are import the dependency in one module you cant use it in other modules include parent module.